# Clearing the terminal is not working

Tags: c++, linux

I know you're not suppose to use system("clear") but my professor insists on using it. For some reason tho, it's not working. I'm on a linux system and using the default terminal in ubuntu 13.04 64bit. I've tried both the cout version and system clear with cstdlib uncluded. Still no success T.T

`system("clear");`

`cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";`

EDIT1: using the g++ compiler. It's also running in a "driver" program. So one cpp file tries to clear the screen and the other prints the code. I don't think it makes a difference though.

Comment: If it's not working, and your professor insists on it, then it's his problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "not working" (what *does* it do?) and what you mean by "driver program". Especially the latter sounds extremely suspicious.

Comment: @us2012 it's not really a driver program. That's what he calls it because it runs all of the methods. The program acts as if nothing happens when clear is called, so it prints a bunch of data that's suppose to look like it's flashing across the screen

Comment: Did you test putting "clear" on the terminal without calling it from a C++ program?

Comment: Yes, putting clear in the terminal works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{ 
    system( "clear" ); return 0;
}
```

and this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{ 
    system( "clear" ); return 0;
}
```

using:
`g++ main.cpp -o system`

both worked for me.
Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Did you notice that this question is since Oct 2nd? :S

Comment: @RanRegev It's from 2013, I wanted to answer and elaborate on this as well, but decided it was too old to get any response from the author.